# Customize log format in python Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-functions

I am writing many Python Azure Functions. I want every line in logs to be prefixed with `invocation-id` from `context` to segregate and correlate the logs easily.

I know there are [multiple ways](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) to do this for a normal/stand-alone python application. Here Azure Function runtime provides an environment where it invokes my code. I don't-want-to/prefer-not-to:

- mess around with existing handlers/formatters registered by Azure Function runtime or
- write my own handlers/formatters

(because whatever is registered by default sends the logs to Azure Log Analytics workspace and powers my dashboards etc)

E.g. following code:

```
import logging
from azure import functions as func

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, ctx: func.Context) -> None:
    logging.info('entry')
    logging.info('invocation id of this run: %s', ctx.invocation_id)
    logging.debug('doing something...')
    logging.info('exit with success')
```

will produce logs like:

```
entry
invocation id of this run: 111-222-33-4444
doing something...
exit with success
```

what I want instead is:

```
(111-222-33-4444) entry
(111-222-33-4444) invocation id of this run: 111-222-33-4444
(111-222-33-4444) doing something...
(111-222-33-4444) exit with success
```

I've seen [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-logging) on Azure, seem useless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LoggerAdapter` to do this, as shown by the following runnable program:

```
import logging

class Adapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        return '(%s) %s' % (self.extra['context'], msg), kwargs

def main(msg, ctx):
    logger = Adapter(logging.getLogger(), {'context': ctx})
    logger.info('entry')
    logger.info('invocation id of this run: %s', ctx)
    logger.debug('doing something ...')
    logger.info('exit with success')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    main('hello', '111-222-33-4444')
```

Obviously I've removed the Azure references so that I can run it locally, but you should get the gist. The preceding script prints

```
(111-222-33-4444) entry
(111-222-33-4444) invocation id of this run: 111-222-33-4444
(111-222-33-4444) doing something ...
(111-222-33-4444) exit with success
```

**Update:** If you don't want to/can't use `LoggerAdapter`, then you can subclass `Logger` as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) or use a `Filter` as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information). But in the latter case you'd still have to attach the filter to all loggers (or handlers, which would be easier) of interest.

Comment: Thanks. But this is just like a wrapper object, which I'll have to pass-around/create-in every function/module I call. Will work only for MY code. E.g. if I'm using some library that logs using `logging.info()` those logs won't be prefixed.

Comment: @Kashyap could you find a "better" solution that works without passing around the context and also would work in external libs?

Comment: @rontron, no, I didn't use it, but I did figure out that the most common technique used is called MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context). See if https://pypi.org/project/mdc/ will work for you. I guess you'll decorate your entry function with `@with_mdc(iid='123')` and then use the `iid` in log format pattern. Thing I could not figure out is how/where to set the format. May be add a new Handler with new pattern?